# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Being curious: what were the criteria for selecting the review questions?

Comment: I think that a lot of questions this time demonstrated the problems of the self-evaluation system as it is for our sites (and arguably language sites in general), as they are totally unsearchable in general (like [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15405)) or searching them turns out a lot of unrelated stuff such as results from dictionaries – no matter how well you tune your search (like [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15327), if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does the verb "möchten" exist?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/does-the-verb-m%c3%b6chten-exist)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is it “sponsern” and not “sponsorn”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/why-is-it-sponsern-and-not-sponsorn)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Besser als meines – why "meines"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15386/besser-als-meines-why-meines)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do I ask for my coffee "for here"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15327/how-do-i-ask-for-my-coffee-for-here)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Difference between “häufig”, “gewöhnlich” and “üblich”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/difference-between-h%c3%a4ufig-gew%c3%b6hnlich-and-%c3%bcblich)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Translation of „Lieber mit einer Flamme im Bett, als mit einer Leuchte am Schreibtisch.“](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/translation-of-lieber-mit-einer-flamme-im-bett-als-mit-einer-leuchte-am-schrei)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Trennt man "die man schläft" mit Kommas/Beistrichen ab?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/trennt-man-die-man-schl%c3%a4ft-mit-kommas-beistrichen-ab)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [“einmal in der Woche” vs. “einmal die Woche”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/einmal-in-der-woche-vs-einmal-die-woche)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- ["Jetzt dreht der Trainer am ganz großen Rad"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/jetzt-dreht-der-trainer-am-ganz-gro%c3%9fen-rad)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [German weasel words](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/german-weasel-words)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 6)

---